# Writing update function haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to create an update function of the following type of 2 inputs. All it does is that it finds n same integers in a list of given integers, deletes them and gives back a new list with all the previous elements plus the n deleted integer in the tail.

```
Int->[Int]->[Int]
```

Example:

```
>update 1 []
[1]
>update 2 [2]
[2]
>update 3 [3,4,3,5,3,6]
[4,5,6,3]
```

Comment: Can you write out the base case?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want and what you've tried.  I think you want `update = (++[n]) . filter (/= n)`, right?  You should show some code.  Showing what you tried helps you learn instead of using the internet as a write-me-a-code-snippet service.

Comment: If you are trying to implement sets, you should probably look at `Data.Set` instead of using linked lists.

Comment: @Lazersmoke If one is trying to *use* sets, that is good advice. If one is trying to *implement* sets, then using an existing implementation defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would write the update function based on my understanding of your question.

```
update :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
update n ns = [ x | x <- ns, x /= n] ++ [n]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case "n" refers to the number of occurrences, and your examples misspecify:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

count y  =  foldl' (n x -> if x == y then n + 1 else n) 0
update y xs = filter (/= y) xs ++ replicate (count y xs) y
```

Or, using the single-traversal `partition`:

```
update y xs = let (ys, other) = partition (== y) xs in other ++ ys
```